# app does not showing interface after logging in

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I've created a chatting application it was working in his initial days and now i've launched this app on the emulator and it does not showing interface after logging in

Inital home interface:

[image: inital home interface]

After logging in:

[image: after logging in]

Stackoverflow is not allowing to showcase entire logcat it is considering as a spam so im uploading on the [github](https://github.com/ruturaj-gh/Chatting_Application/blob/master/logcat.pdf)

The entire [code](https://github.com/ruturaj-gh/Chatting_Application)

```
2022-11-27 17:45:34.164 11474-11530/? E/bmsm: RuntimeException while executing runnable bmvj{bayk@4d5b589} with executor MoreExecutors.directExecutor()
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String azvn.b' on a null object reference in method 'void bayk.b(java.lang.Object)'
        at bayk.b(PG:2)
        at bmvj.run(PG:7)
        at bmun.execute(PG:1)
        at bmsm.o(PG:1)
        at bmsm.d(PG:5)
        at bmvq.r(PG:2)
        at baym.a(PG:15)
        at aazg.a(PG:2)
        at baav.m(PG:3)
        at azzr.a(Unknown Source:4)
        at bmsq.b(PG:2)
        at bmss.run(PG:9)
        at bmws.run(PG:4)
        at axmd.run(PG:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
        at axli.run(PG:3)
        at axlp.run(PG:4)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
2022-11-27 17:45:34.180 11474-11593/? E/bbqj: Non-success http response code 416 for: 
2022-11-27 17:45:39.703 11474-12019/? E/bbqj: Non-success http response code 416 for: 
2022-11-27 17:45:45.613 11474-11531/? E/MDD: DownloadProgressMonitor: Can't find file group for uri: android://com.google.android.apps.messaging/files/datadownload/shared/public/datadownloadfile_1669550705711
2022-11-27 17:46:42.960 410-410/? E/android.hardware.power.stats@1.0-service-mock: Failed to getEnergyData
2022-11-27 17:47:31.188 583-613/? E/libprocessgroup: Failed to kill process cgroup uid 10142 pid 8938 in 3
2022-11-27 18:00:11.600 1500-2075/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 404)
2022-11-27 18:00:12.658 1155-2248/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 252)
2022-11-27 18:00:13.235 12432-12432/? E/d.process.acore: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2022-11-27 18:00:16.572 387-447/? E/android.hardware.audio@7.0-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/stream_out.cpp:updateSourceMetadata:378 failure: Result::NOT_SUPPORTED
2022-11-27 18:00:16.612 387-5735/? E/android.hardware.audio@7.0-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/talsa.cpp:mixerGetOrOpenImpl:55 failure: nullptr
2022-11-27 18:00:16.613 387-5735/? E/android.hardware.audio@7.0-impl.ranchu: pcmOpen:128 pcm_open failed for nChannels=2 sampleRateHz=48000 frameCount=1056 isOut=1 with cannot open device (0) for card (0): No such file or directory
2022-11-27 18:00:16.614 387-5735/? E/android.hardware.audio@7.0-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/talsa.cpp:pcmOpen:131 failure: nullptr
2022-11-27 18:00:16.618 387-5735/? E/android.hardware.audio@7.0-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/device_port_sink.cpp:create:218 failure: nullptr
2022-11-27 18:00:16.814 387-447/? E/android.hardware.audio@7.0-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/stream_out.cpp:updateSourceMetadata:378 failure: Result::NOT_SUPPORTED
2022-11-27 18:00:17.972 387-447/? E/android.hardware.audio@7.0-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/stream_out.cpp:updateSourceMetadata:378 failure: Result::NOT_SUPPORTED
2022-11-27 18:00:18.151 387-447/? E/android.hardware.audio@7.0-impl.ranchu: device/generic/goldfish/audio/stream_out.cpp:updateSourceMetadata:378 failure: Result::NOT_SUPPORTED
2022-11-27 18:00:42.984 410-410/? E/android.hardware.power.stats@1.0-service-mock: Failed to getEnergyData
```

Comment: Show us the code the produces that error.

Comment: @AlexMamo  Im not getting the error where it is coming from , do you use discord or something where i can ask ?

Comment: Sorry @Ruturajghumkar, but that's not how Stack Overflow works. "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Is your code obfuscated or is this framework code? `azvn.b' on a null object reference in method 'void bayk.b`